# Gradle cannot find compose compiler

Tags: android, gradle

I want to implement jetpack compose in my existing project in `Dynamic Feature Module`. I was following the [setup guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup) from [official jetpack compose website](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose) but got this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':features:profile:workpreferences:prepareStagingDebugKotlinCompileTask'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':features:profile:workpreferences:kotlin-extension'.
   > Could not find androidx.compose:compose-compiler:1.0.0-beta01.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/compose/compose-compiler/1.0.0-beta01/compose-compiler-1.0.0-beta01.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/compose/compose-compiler/1.0.0-beta01/compose-compiler-1.0.0-beta01.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/compose/compose-compiler/1.0.0-beta01/compose-compiler-1.0.0-beta01.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/androidx/compose/compose-compiler/1.0.0-beta01/compose-compiler-1.0.0-beta01.pom
       - https://dl.bintray.com/guardian/android/androidx/compose/compose-compiler/1.0.0-beta01/compose-compiler-1.0.0-beta01.pom
     Required by:
         project :features:profile:workpreferences

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

I have tried some approach to solve this issue but nothing works.

- gradle version = `7.0.0-alpha08`
- kotlin version = `1.4.30`
- compose version = `1.0.0-beta01`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this same error too and then took a look at the Jetpack Compose Sample apps here: https://github.com/android/compose-samples

I realized all the samples they have uses the Android Gradle Plugin version: 7.0.0-alpha08 AND the gradle version: 6.8.2 so I recommend making sure your app has that. Once I updated I no longer saw that error, but I did notice there are some third party libraries that don't have support for that AGP so be prepared for that. [android-jetpack-compose](/questions/tagged/android-jetpack-compose)

Comment: thanks @user14158634 for your answer. You're correct, this issue solved by upgrading `agp to 7.0.0-alpha08` and `gradle version 6.8.2` After I re-setup jetpack compose in my project I realized that previously I was not completely upgrading those agp things. And when I upgrade it correctly, the error were gone.